# SQL statement converted to Linq

Tags: sql, linq

I need to convert the following SQL statement into LINQ.  I'm basically moving from a view on the database to a piece of LINQ and I am struggling with the getting the NOT IN and inner Select working

```
SELECT  DISTINCT *  

FROM TFund F3,TFundMapping FM

WHERE F3.ID NOT IN 
(SELECT ParentFundID
 FROM TFundMapping)
AND FM.ChildFundID = F3.ID
```

As a bit of background, for my other LINQ queries I use the following style

```
public TxxxType[] GetxxxType()
    {
        var query = from item in _context.TxxxType
                    orderby item.ID
                    select item;

        return _context.SelectPOCOsWCF(query);
    }
```

I just can't seem to get the syntax correct and fitted into the above style - any help will be appreciated as I'm hitting a brick wall on this one

Many Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should go to this web site http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b and figure this out by yourself.

Comment: Purely a time issue on this one - I am currently looking into how to write this into LINQ, but I'm up against the clock today as this is just a tiny bit of a much bigger piece that I'm trying to complete in the next few hours - just one of those days :)

Answer (score 0):

This tool will help you to achieve your goal

http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, but its untested:

```
var result = ( from record in _context.TFund

               join fundMappingRecord in _context.TFundMapping
                 on record.ID equals fundMappingRecord.ChildFundID

               where ( from subResult in _context.TFundMapping
                       select subResult.ParentFundID 
                     ).Contains( record.ID ) == false 

               select new 
               {
                   record,
                   fundMappingRecord
               } ).Distinct( );
```

You'll still have a problem because you cannot pass an anonymous type to another method.